# WSL -- Command Not Found

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running the following command in PowerShell `wsl pipenv run python ~/test.py` and receive the following error `/bin/bash: pipenv: command not found`. If I launch WSL/Ubuntu, I can run `pipenv run python ~/test.py` and get a successful output. In PowerShell and Git Bash, I can run `pipenv -h` and get proper output. Where does WSL look for this command?

On a related note, I can run `python ~/test.py` and `python3 ./test.py` when I launch WSL/Ubuntu and get successful output. But from PowerShell, only `wsl python3 ~/test.py` works. When I run `wsl python ~/test.py` I receive the same command not found error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on our comments exchange, the problem is that the directory in which the `pipenv` executable is located - `/home/<username>/.local/bin/` -  isn't present in the `PATH` environment variable when invoking a command *non-interactively*.

This suggests that it is an *initialization file* that extends `PATH`, and it seems that it is `~/.bash_profile` in your case; to force an explicit `bash` invocation to source this file, the `-l` (`--login`) option must be passed.

You report that the following command ultimately worked for you:

```
bash -l -c "cd ~ && pipenv run python ~/test.py"
```

---

Note:

- An explicit invocation with `-c` is what `wsl.exe` does behind the scenes when you pass it a command to execute, albeit without `-l` (e.g. `wsl date` turns into `bash -c date`).

  - The use of `-c` makes the shell *non*-[interactive](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Interactive-Shells.html), which means that `~/.bashrc` isn't sourced either; if you want the latter, add `-i`
- Without a command (executing just `wsl.exe` or `bash.exe`), an interactive `bash` shell is entered, which - in effect - *does* use `-l`, and therefore automatically sources `~/.bash_profile` (`wsl.exe` / `bash.exe` use the alternative mechanism for requesting a login shell: the first entry of the argument array (which you can inspect with `echo $0`) is set to `-bash`, and the initial `-` tells Bash to start a login shell).

See also: <sup>Thanks, 
[Zymotik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314472/zymotik).</sup>

- [Invoking Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html)
- [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)

Comment: `bash -l` is short for `bash --login`

See [invoking bash].(https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html)

This will make the shell act as if it had been directly invoked by login. When the shell is interactive, this is equivalent to starting a login shell with ‘exec -l bash’. When the shell is not interactive, the login shell startup files will be executed. See [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html), for a description of the special behaviour of a login shell.
@mklement0 thank you, I've removed my comment.

Comment: Thanks, @Zymotik - I've folded your links into the answer, along with a more detailed explanation.